# applying templates of same type but working on different type of declaration

Tags: xslt

I've below XMLs.

```
 <emphasis type="italic">
                  varying from ti,e to time<star.page>58</star.page>Starch
                </emphasis>
```

and

```
<para indent="no">
   <star.page>18</star.page> Further to same.
</para>
```

here i'm trying to `apply-templates` on the `star.page`, but the confusion is if i take `<xsl:apply-templates select="./*[1][self::star.page]" mode="first"/>`, it is working fine for the first case, but for the second case, the `star.page` is getting duplicated, if i use `<xsl:apply-templates select="./node()[1][self::star.page]" mode="first"/>`, in `case 2` the star.page that is supposed to appear before `div` is coming inside `div` and for `case 1`, the value is getting duplicated.

Here are the DEmos

Case1-[enter link description here](http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiJ7/1)
Case2- [enter link description here](http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaF5/4)

Expected output are as below.

Case 1:

```
<span class="font-style-italic">
      varying from ti,e to time<?pb label='58'?><a name="pg_58"></a></span>2<span class="font-style-italic">Starch
      </span>
```

Case 2:

```
   <?pb label='18'?><a name="pg_18"></a>
   <div class="para">
       Further to same.

   </div>
```

Here the condition is as below.

1. If `star.page` is immediate child of parent node(though it is `para` or `emphasis`), the `pb label` has to be created first followed by the tag(Case 2 output).
2. If there is text and in between text there is `star.page`, then the content should come with pb label inside it.(Case 1 output).

please let me know a common solution on how i can fix theses issues.

Comment: Are you trying to make your meta-syntax for text formatting? If yes, you don't have to do it in that monstrous way, you do in the files I have just looked through. If no, I have no idea, what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't get you

Comment: I mean, if I understand the task you're trying to accomplish, you make it in a very complicated way. You should clean your code of all those CDATA fragments to make it more simple to operate. Here is just a small example of my xsl to match common and custom tags and attributes: http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzQb/2

Comment: Can you show the expected output for both your samples in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @TimC, I've added expected outputs. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not clear what the bulk of your XSLT is doing, but I would first make use of a named template to avoid repeated code. There is no issue with giving a matched template a name too.

```
<xsl:template match="star.page" name="page">
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="pb">
        <xsl:text>label='</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>?</xsl:text>
    </xsl:processing-instruction>
    <a name="{concat('pg_',.)}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Then the template with the mode "first" becomes this

```
<xsl:template match="star.page" mode="first">
    <xsl:call-template name="page" />
</xsl:template>
```

You can still call this in the same way, or maybe a slightly different condition will also work

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="star.page[not(preceding-sibling::node())]" mode="first"/>
```

Then, all you need is a template to ignore "star.page" that are the first child (because they have already been explicitly selected)

```
 <xsl:template match="star.page[not(preceding-sibling::node())]" />
```

As a simplified example, try this for starers

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="para|emphasis">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="star.page[not(preceding-sibling::node())]" mode="first"/>

        <div>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="./@align">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:text>para align-</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="./@align"/></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:text>para</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="star.page[not(preceding-sibling::node())]" />

    <xsl:template match="star.page" name="page">
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="pb">
            <xsl:text>label='</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>?</xsl:text>
        </xsl:processing-instruction>
        <a name="{concat('pg_',.)}"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="star.page" mode="first">
        <xsl:call-template name="page" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do note the use of `strip-space` here because strictly speaking, the `star.page` is not the first node in each example, there is a white-space node before it.

When applied to this XML

```
<root>
    <emphasis type="italic">
      varying from ti,e to time<star.page>58</star.page>Starch
    </emphasis>
    <para indent="no">
       <star.page>18</star.page> Further to same.
    </para>
</root>
```

The following is output

```
<div class="para">
  varying from time to time<?pb label='58'??><a name="pg_58"/>Starch
</div>

<?pb label='18'??>
<a name="pg_18"/>
    <div class="para"> Further to same.
</div>
```

Comment: just want to know one thing, does `strip-spaces`, remove spaces just before the node, or the content even?

Comment: The spaces before the node, and the content of the node are both "text nodes" as far as XML is concerned. `strip-space` will remove any text node consisting solely of whitespace.

Comment: Hi Tim, Can you please have a look into below. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27401675/close-the-number-of-parent-and-ancestor-tags